# composite key using EF code-first 4.3 using data annotations

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first, data-annotations

in my project, i have a class with two primary keys and am not sure what i am doing wrong. below is an example of what i currently have written. from about a half hour of looking around google/stack overflow has led me to the [Key, Column(order=)] tag. however this is not working in my code and was wondering if i could get any assistance

```
public class Example{

    [Key, Column(order=0)
    [Required]
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int FirstProperty { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(order=1)
    [Required]
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int SecondProperty { get; set; }

}
```

when i try to run, the error i am getting is as follows

```
One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

System.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'Example' has no key defined. define the key for this EntityType.
```

thanks

Comment: If you get error during compilation it means you are not using code first. Code first mapping is not evaluated during compilation. It is evaluated at runtime when the model is created during the first usage of the context. Do you have EDMX file in your project?

Comment: @LadislavMrnka - i apologize, it was during runtime

Comment: Shouldn't you be using the model builder to define the database schema? Why pollute your POCOs with annotations?

Comment: @Yuck I'm sorry, I'm a student and haven't gotten any industry experience (yet), so I apologize if my code is badly formatted,